# Which wine do I need to use itunes

Tags: wine, itunes

I am looking in the Ubuntu software center for wine to run iTunes. There are several options, but I'd thought i'd ask, which one is the right one to get? Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, itunes doesn't work well in wine, which makes the version of wine irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mike already said it doesn't work well, see also the winehq app database: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1347
If you really want to use itunes, I suggest you use Virtualbox.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the linux alternative called gtkpod for your ipod, it's in the software centre...